# Connect MySQL and Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to connect MYSQL Database with Chrome Extension?.

My Application needs data to be stored in a database.

Tried other methods such as WebSQL and IndexDb but i want to get that any browsers.

Comment: If you are building a Chrome extension then it will work only in Chrome, so you can safely use WebSQL that is supported by this browser.

Comment: You could write an ODBC database driver using the `chrome.socket` API (note: this is an insane suggestion; don't do it), but that would be even *less* supported across browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish it to work in Chrome - I would go for indexedDB.
If you wish it to work on other browsers (but in this case, you will need to change your extension code to fit FF, Safari etc') - I would try to use some abstraction layer like: http://brian.io/lawnchair/ that will allow you to enjot both world of WebSQL and IndexedDB depend on the browser you are working in.

One important thing to remember is that WebSQL is deprecated API since 2010 - So you wish to work with indexDB when you can.

MySQL won't be a good solution since you can't control the env. and make sure that your Chrome users will have it installed.